# Getting data from another URL using form input and reading that data

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker, get

I am trying to do something that I think should be relatively straightforward but I am not sure exactly how to do it and despite much searching and looking through examples, I am still not sure how to do it.

I have a form which has a date input field and a days (7/14) selector and when the use changes either the date or the days it should query a separate URL and then return the results.

The problem I have is:

How to select date/days in the form but read the URL and not redirect the user but refresh the page to echo the results from reading the URL?

I have put together a simple example to show what I mean:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>$( function() { $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker(); } ); </script>
</head>
<body>

<?php
// Example fully formatted URL 
http://www.angelfishbooking.co.uk/feeds/roomavailability.aspx?id=Belle_Tout&date=2017-06-23&days=7
// http://www.angelfishbooking.co.uk/feeds/roomavailability.aspx?id=Belle_Tout&date=[DATESELECTED]&days=[DAYSSELECTED]
?>

<form action="http://www.angelfishbooking.co.uk/feeds/roomavailability.aspx?id=Belle_Tout&" method="GET">
<input class="datepicker" type="text" id="datepicker" name="date" value="">
<select><option value="7" id="days" name="days">7 days</option><option value="14">14 days</option></select>
<input type="hidden" name="c" value="3" /> 
<input type="submit" /> 
</form>
</body>

<?php
// Read contents of the URL
// dateselected = datepicker output
//$angelfish = file_get_contents('http://www.angelfishbooking.co.uk/feeds/roomavailability.aspx?id=Belle_Tout&date=' . $dateselected . '&days=' . $days);
// Display contents of the URL, i.e.

echo '<hr>';
echo 'Show example output that we are trying to achieve using above 
selection but with defaults of date today and days of 7.';
echo '<br /><br />';
$dateselected = date('Y-m-d');
$daysselected = '7';
$angelfish = file_get_contents('http://www.angelfishbooking.co.uk/feeds/roomavailability.aspx?id=Belle_Tout&date=' . $dateselected . '&days=' . $daysselected);
echo $angelfish;

//At this point we'll format nicely with coloured rows, etc
?>
</body>
```

Would someone be able to point me in the right direction?

Many thanks,

Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<pre>Please use below code <?php
$dateselected = date('Y-m-d');
$daysselected = '7';
if(isset($_POST['date']) && isset($_POST['days'])){
    $dateselected=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['date']));
    $daysselected = $_POST['days'];
}
?>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>$( function() { $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker(); } ); </script>
</head>
<body>

<?php
// Example fully formatted URL 
http://www.angelfishbooking.co.uk/feeds/roomavailability.aspx?id=Belle_Tout&date=2017-06-23&days=7
// http://www.angelfishbooking.co.uk/feeds/roomavailability.aspx?id=Belle_Tout&date=[DATESELECTED]&days=[DAYSSELECTED]
?>

<form name="form1" method="POST">
<input class="datepicker" type="text" id="datepicker" name="date" value="">
<select name="days"><option value="7" id="days" name="days">7 days</option><option value="14">14 days</option></select>
<input type="hidden" name="c" value="3" /> 
<input type="submit" /> 
</form>
</body>

<?php
// Read contents of the URL
// dateselected = datepicker output
//$angelfish = file_get_contents('http://www.angelfishbooking.co.uk/feeds/roomavailability.aspx?id=Belle_Tout&date=' . $dateselected . '&days=' . $days);
// Display contents of the URL, i.e.

echo '<hr>';
echo 'Show example output that we are trying to achieve using above 
selection but with defaults of date today and days of 7.';
echo '<br /><br />';
echo 'http://www.angelfishbooking.co.uk/feeds/roomavailability.aspx?id=Belle_Tout&date=' . $dateselected . '&days=' . $daysselected."<bR>";
 $angelfish = file_get_contents('http://www.angelfishbooking.co.uk/feeds/roomavailability.aspx?id=Belle_Tout&date=' . $dateselected . '&days=' . $daysselected);
echo $angelfish;

//At this point we'll format nicely with coloured rows, etc
?>
</body></pre>
```

Comment: Jackson, that's brilliant, thank you very much, I am very impressed.